# twitter link issue (the same link inserted by different ways give different tweet lenght)

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ios, objective-c, twitter

I want to insert link in text:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *composeController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
composeController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[composeController setInitialText:NSLocalizedString(kTwitterText, nil)];
[composeController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

but first I tried to insert big links, and I had 4 extra characters (I need to remove them to post a tweet), then I used bit.ly and created short links, but never the less I have 4 extra characters.

1) So the link width is not important and twitter always replace it with its own link?

2) OK, but why when I add these links in  `[composeController setInitialText:NSLocalizedString(kTwitterText, nil)]`  (not in `[composeController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];`)  everything is ok. So do twitter add some extra characters (hidden), when we use  `[composeController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];`  ?

**Update:**

But when I use goo.gl shorter (which I really only 2 charachters shorter than link from lit.ly), it gives me 15 extra symbols (I can write in addition to text and link will be posted). It seems that twitter don't change goo.gl links, but do change others.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq#How_long_are_t.co_links

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found out the answer (I suppose that it's true base on my 2 hour investigation, but anyway it works) (I dublicated the answer because at first I chose community wiki):

when you post link to twitter, twitter tries to shorten your link, but it does it in a clever way.

twitter's shorten url is 15 characters in length. So if you url is larger it will be shorten.

but if your url is smaller twitter text will be filled by your shorter url (but anyway when you try to get the link at twitter account, you will see that url is changed anyway, but in fact that changed url doesn't influence your tweet length, the length will be filled only with your shorter link url).

I got shorter link at bit.ly (14 characters), but that wasn't enough for me, because I need 12, but then I found that I can change domain to j.mp (at the settings of my bit.ly account) and that gave me 12 characters length.

**update:**
on iOS 5 if your link width is more then 12, you can face different issues (populated text can not be long, by the way, if your link width is 15 you should reduce text length by 15 characters, strange, but it is so)